# Search for keyword instead of whole word - py

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, trie, prefix-tree

My hash codes returns only the whole title of the word.
I want to make it to show the results with only using keywords
for at least 2 word (onwards) then show the results (get function).

**My hash code**

```
class hashin:
def __init__(self):
    self.size = 217  # size of hash table
    self.map = [None] * self.size

def _get_hash(self, key):
    hash = 0
    for char in str(key):
        hash += ord(char)
    return hash % self.size
#returns the ASCII value of char in str(key)

def add(self, key, value):  # add item to list
    key_hash = self._get_hash(key)
    key_value = [key, value]
    if self.map[key_hash] is None:
        self.map[key_hash] = list([key_value])
        return True
    else:
        for pair in self.map[key_hash]:
            if pair[0] == key:
                pair[1] = value
                return True
        self.map[key_hash].append(key_value)
        return True

def get(self, key):  # search for item
    key_hash = self._get_hash(key)
    if self.map[key_hash] is not None:
        for pair in self.map[key_hash]:  # find pair of words
            if pair[0] == key:  # if pair is equals to the whole title of the word
                return pair[0] + " - " + pair[1]
    return "Error no results for %s \nEnter the correct word." % (key)
```

sample outputs:

when whole title was typed

[image: Sample Output search (needs to have the whole word in order to show)]

When keyword was typed (i need to show the results even when keyword was typed)

[image: no results when keyword is typed]

What i need is :
Output:
Cheater - Kygos
and the other words with chea in their name

Comment: You could explain better, you could show examples of inputs and outputs to understand you better.

Comment: In addition to that has relation with pyqt, since the functionality that samples do not need of pyqt as it shows your code.

Comment: sorry, I will try to repolish my question again then post a pics about it

Comment: What are some example values of `key` ?

Comment: @ChickenFeet key = any word, key_hash = ASCII number value, key_value = [word1,word2]

Comment: You could share your CSV file so that you can test please.

Comment: [link csv](http://www.mediafire.com/file/gqz18a7wf84dq5w/musics.csv)

Answer (score 0):

A hash table isn't the right data structure for this task.  The purpose of a hash value is to narrow the search to a small subset of the possibilities.  Since the hash value is dependent on the entire string, using just a portion of the string will give the wrong subset.

A better data structure for this task is a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (sometimes called a "prefix tree").  While it is not difficult to write this data structure on your own, there are already many tested, ready-to-use modules already available on PyPI.

See:
  https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=trie&submit=search